# float: right doesn't work

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have two div's which classes are left and right. left is floated to left and right div is floated to right, but float doesn't work, I don't know why... I can't setup width in left div because I don't know right div images width's. So it's need to be fluid...
here is page:
link removed. sorry

and here is page where it's work's.
http://www.france24.com/en/20100111-freud-monet-basquiat-view-paris-2010

I spend on this 3 hours, I don't know why right is not floating...

**Upd**: The problem fixed! Thank you ;)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that page.  What exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't float the article content left; it does nothing. Instead, take the items you wish to float to the right, and put them *above* the main content. That's just how floats work. If you find that it doesn't work, even after testing, try again :P

Comment: oh work's when I removed float left from left, and putting right div before left :)) Thank you!

Comment: Good :) I'm sure you know this, but in order to ensure you aren't breaking anything else, remove the left *class*, not the style from the left class, in case other things on the site use it. Also, in Google Chrome, I stored a local copy and could only actually make it work after removing the inline-block style from .content, so you may have some further browser-compatibility testing to do.

Comment: "put them above the main content" thats an amazing fact i never know! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The right float needs to be before the left one.

Answer (score 2):

Combine right float with `width`

```
.walk-text {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a spacer to push it to the right

```
 <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
```